# replacing a partial with js in it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rhtml partial "mypartial" which contains a js block like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">new Ajax.Updater([...]);</script>
```

In a rjs template, i call

```
page.replace "container", :partial => "mypartial"
```

the replacement works fine, except for the script block. This block and it's javascript is not going to be written into the html (which i checked with firefox/ web dev toolbar -> show generated source).

Do i really have to write the js part in my rjs template via page << "myjs()" ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own fault, but i will write it down here for anyone who may run into the same problem.

The js code will be evaluated, BUT: it won't work for document.observe('dom:loaded') because this event is going to be triggered when you finished loading a page, not when you update a partial. *facepalming myself*

Answer (score 1):

I find it strange that your `page.replace` would omit the script tags... What if you use the `javascript_tag` helper? Does it omit that as well?

Another option is just to have that JavaScript in one of the JavaScript files that is loaded from your layout. Then you don't have to worry about removing and replacing it. Unless, of course, you're inserting Ruby variables.

If you're using Ruby variables in your JavaScript, then maybe instead of RJS your AJAX call should render down a js.erb template that throws in the JavaScript and then renders the partial.

Comment: unfortunately i have to worry about removing/adding it dynamically, that's why i hoped this works with replace ;)

Comment: oh, and the javascript_tag helper unfortunately hadn't helped

Comment: My suggestion accounts for your dynamic scenario. You don't need RJS for AJAX. RJS is just JavaScript with a Ruby feel. Right now you're making an AJAX call to an RJS action. Instead, you make that AJAX call to an action that renders a js.erb template. Same thing, different syntax. Here's a good example: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Answer (score 1):

The partial will be rendered with the script block intact but, if I remember correctly, Prototype will remove them before it inserts the HTML into the DOM in order to `eval` them later. That's why it doesn't show up in the DOM inspector. You can test this by including an `alert("HELLO FROM RJS")` in the generated script - it should show the alert.

Comment: So that proves that the JavaScript is being executed, so there must be a problem with how it is written. Are there any errors in the JS console?